# $_SESSION not woking in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Firstly I use below code for start session:

```
function sess_start() {
if (!session_id())
    session_start();
}
add_action('init','sess_start');
```

I use `$_session` in wordpress in below method and this works correctly

method 1:

```
$_SESSION['mycity']=4;
```

and in the other page I get `$_SESSION['mycity']` correctly=4.

But when I use the below

method 2:

```
$parent = get_the_category()[1]->cat_ID;     //get_the_category()[1]->cat_ID is = 4
$_SESSION['mycity']=$parent;
```

I get `$_SESSION['mycity']=1`

When I use second method in the footer I get `$_SESSION['mycity']=4` but in the another page I get `$_SESSION['mycity']=1`

now i found that when i use google chrom this problem solved, this problem when accor that i use firefox

Comment: check session_start() at top of the page

Comment: with this function sess_start() i start the session

Comment: It is rather unclear what you are asking, resp. what the actual problem is. `//get_the_category()[1]->cat_ID is = 4` - well that might not actually be the case, if you execute this code in the footer on _every_ page. // Please start by describing what you actually want to _achieve_ here.

Comment: when i logged in in wordpress  $_SESSION not work true and when user not logged in S_SESSION work true this is my main problem

Comment: now i found that when i use google chrom this problem solved, this problem when accor that i use firefox

Comment: Your comment is unclear and your edit to your question is not really an improvement. Could you edit again and try for better readability?